# C# Update Azure Cosmos Db json item with Upsert

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, upsert

I'm (new to CosmosDb) and trying to update an item in an Azure Cosmos db, but it's inserting instead.

The object sent is

```
public class Bank
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I tried passing only the Code and the Name values back (i.e. I did not include the id in the object, which causes an insert (I wanted an update).

I am now including the id which results in an error.

Error returned is:

ResourceType Document is unexpected.
ActivityId: a0d50426-c556-4b17-9646-93052699026e, Windows/10.0.19044 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.16.2

So, it's values after a front end update (only changing the Name value) are:

```
Code: "FNB"
Name: "aa First Update Test"
id:   "d76ade3d-7d02-46e5-a458-e9f0781bf044"
```

[image: Cosmos db image]

The DAL code:

```
var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DBName, "Banks", bank.Code);
try
{
    Document doc = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(documentUri, bank);
}
```

How do I get it to update?

TIA

Comment: Please edit your question and include the partition key attribute of your container. Is it `id` or `Code`? Also, please share the data that is sent to Cosmos DB (essentially the value of your `bank` variable).

Comment: It is id and I have included the Bank object now.

Comment: Thanks! Can you share the exact data that you are sending?

Comment: In Cosmos DB a partition key is mandatory. Otherwise you can't update elements.

Comment: So, is the id then the partition key?

Comment: I have updated the question, with the object sent, it's values vs it's prior to edit/update values (in the image) and a new issue/error, when passing the id field back in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is not clear and dont have enough information.try these functions.

```
protected DataContext(string endpointUrl, string databaseId,   
                      string masterKey)  
{  
    _databaseId = databaseId;  
    _masterKey = masterKey;  
  
    _databaseUri = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_databaseId);  
  
    this._client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), _masterKey);  
  
    this._client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database   
      { Id = _databaseId });  
  
    this._client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(  
      UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_databaseId),   
      new DocumentCollection { Id = CollectionId });  
  
    _databaseCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(  
      _databaseId, CollectionId);  
}
```

insert and update using

```
public async Task<Document> UpsertDocumentAsync(T entity)  
{  
    var result = await this._client.UpsertDocumentAsync(  
    _databaseCollectionUri, entity);  
    return result;  
}
```

Or Try please using the nuget Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

```
 string cosmosDbConnectionString = CosmosDbConnectionKey;
                CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosDbConnectionString);
                var db = CosmosDbNameKey;
                var container = ContainerKey;
                await container.UpsertItemAsync(Model, new PartitionKey(Model.PK));
```

Comment: I don't need to create the DocumentCollection, it is already in the Dbase. I think all I need is the PartitionKey, as presently I'm trying to update an item in a collection based on it's "Code", which is probably not the correct way of doing things.

Comment: Possibly use   new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) })

Comment: If you have a choice, use the v3 SDK and not the v2 SDK. The v3 SDK has been out for years, is faster, more features, better supported.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed was the DocumentCollection (DocumentCollection Link) in the Upsert, but I had the Document Link (documentUri)
So,

```
    public async Task<ExBool> UpdateAsyncPOCO(Bank bank)
    {
        
        //  NB:  UpsertDocumentAsync should take the DocumentCollection link, instead of Document link.
        // This is a DocumentLink
        var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DBName, "Banks", bank.Code);

        // This is a DocumentCollection
        var CollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Banks");


        try
        {
            Document doc = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(CollectionUri, bank);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Insert and update work perfectly now.
The model and values for the update:

```
Code: "updated   FNB 2"
Name: "updated   First National Bank 22"
id: "d76ade3d-7d02-46e5-a458-e9f0781bf044"
```

Similarly, the Insert

```
Code: "qwerty"
Name: "qwertyuiop"
id: ""
```